# How to append header arguments to result code src block?

Tags: org-babel

For example, I have an src code block which can generate another code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results code :wrap systemd
systemctl --user cat rslsync.service
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_systemd
# /usr/lib/systemd/user/rslsync.service
[Unit]
Description=Resilio Sync service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rslsync
Group=rslsync
ConditionPathExists=/run/media/stardiviner/Collections
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rslsync --nodaemon --config /etc/rslsync.conf
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
#+END_systemd
```

I wish to append header argument `:tangle "/sudo::/usr/lib/systemd/user/rslsync.service"` to
upper result code block.

Comment: `:wrap "systemd :tangle /path"` works for me.

Comment: @mutbuerger Thanks, this solved my question. Can you post an answer. So I can pick your answer as my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional header arguments by using double quotes around the `:wrap` argument: `:wrap "systemd :tangle /path"`.